# Using endlocal set variables in a batch file, but the variables are never available outside of the setlocal/endlocal block

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to set the value of a variable that is inside a SETLOCAL, inside a FOR loop and inside an IF statement. However, it never seems to work. I tried using a SET statement at the ENDLOCAL statement, but that doesn't seem to actually set anything. Echoing the variable after that only echos the original set value of 0.

```
@ECHO off

SET pathsource=K:
SET sourcefile=0
SET counter=0

SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

REM Get the newest pptx file in the specified directory. Get the filename and last modified timestamp
FOR /f "tokens=1-3,5*" %%a IN ('dir ^"%pathsource%\*.pptx^" /a-d-h-s /o-d /tw ^| find /i ^".pptx^"') DO (
    REM echo !counter!

    REM only get the first row by using a counter
    IF !counter! EQU 0 (
        REM variables are: a-date, b-time, c-am/pm, d&e-filename
        ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e

        SET sourcefile=%%d %%e
    )

    SET /A counter+=1
)


ENDLOCAL & (
    SET "sourcefile=%sourcefile%"
)

ECHO %sourcefile%

REM do other stuff with the %sourcefile% variable after this
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you assign the values within the Set/End Local block, any changes made within this are discarded once on the `ENDLOCAL` command is reached.

Just move your `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` commands to the very top and bottom of your script respectively. This would make all assignments made within the entirety of script stick throughout.

---

Additionally, you don't really need the counter variable. You can just jump out of the loop after the first file is processed:

```
@ECHO off
REM delayed expansion not needed for the portion shown
SETLOCAL enableextensions

SET pathsource=K:
SET sourcefile=0

REM Get the newest pptx file in the specified directory. Get the filename and last modified timestamp
FOR /f "tokens=1-3,5*" %%a IN ('dir ^"%pathsource%\*.pptx^" /a-d-h-s /o-d /tw ^| find /i ^".pptx^"') DO (
    REM variables are: a-date, b-time, c-am/pm, d&e-filename
    ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e

    SET sourcefile=%%d %%e

    REM We only care about the first row
    GOTO EndLoop
)

:EndLoop
ECHO %sourcefile%

REM do other stuff with the %sourcefile% variable after this

ENDLOCAL
```

One last thing is you can simply your `FOR` syntax a bit by using native `DIR` and `FOR` variable commands:

```
@ECHO off
REM delayed expansion not needed for the portion shown
SETLOCAL enableextensions

SET pathsource=K:
SET sourcefile=0

REM Get the newest pptx file in the specified directory. Get the filename and last modified timestamp
CD "%pathsource%\"
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a IN (`dir "%pathsource%\*.pptx" /a-d-h-s /o-d /tw /b`) DO (
    REM Use For loop variables.
    REM Print the date/time and file name.
    ECHO %%~ta %%~a

    SET sourcefile=%%~a

    REM We only care about the first row
    GOTO EndLoop
)

:EndLoop
ECHO %sourcefile%

REM do other stuff with the %sourcefile% variable after this

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I think the OP tries to use tunneling - http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=3712#p3712

Comment: Ahh, I see. In this use case though, it shouldn't be needed. Delayed expansion can be safely disabled within the context of the portion posted.

Comment: Thanks, those revisions were very helpful. :) However, the %%~ta variable only ever outputs "echo is off" and %%~a spits out the whole row "11/07/2013  02:30 PM            57,309 slideshow.pptx".

Comment: @ForceFlow - I can't reproduce (works for me). I'm using Win 7, what OS are you using? FYI, you can see all the available file manipulations available in the `FOR /?` documentation. This is where I got the `%%~ta` syntax from.

Comment: @ForceFlow - To be sure, are you using the `dir` command from your original script (which pipes output to a `find`) or in my last revision which uses the native `dir` output? I'm not sure if the shortcuts would work in the piped output.

Comment: Win7. I pretty much copied and pasted your code as-is (all I did was changed some SET variables and ECHO statements). I am not piping to a `find`.

Comment: @ForceFlow - I updated the second snip with the entire script - just to be sure. Unrelated - are you the same ForceFlow from PCMech?

Comment: @ForceFlow, The `dir` command is not including the file path, so, the replaceable parameter will only include the filename without the path and the file will not be found. As is, the code will not retrieve the date time of the file  if the current active directory is not `%pathsource%`.

Comment: Still not seeing the timestamp. Maybe it's because filenames with spaces don't allow it to properly detect things? http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1314225565692 Yes, I'm the same FF.

Comment: Nope, spaces in the filename don't matter--I just checked.

Comment: @ForceFlow - I see the problem. It is what @MC ND mentioned above. In order to use the `%%~ta` expansion, the current path has to be where you are searching. Since you are not using the `/S` switch on the `dir` command, you first need to `CD` to the path you are searching. I have updated the answer to include the `CD` command prior to the `FOR` loop.

Comment: @ForceFlow - Small world, I used to write for PCMech many moons ago. :)

Comment: I needed to use `CD /D %pathsource%` since the drive letter isn't the c-drive, but other than that, it looks like it's working now. Thanks :) Yeah, I remember you--if you're interested in writing again, floppyman is in charge now. :p

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the name and timestamp of the newest PPTX file, your script is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  Simply scrape `dir "path\*.pptx" /b /o:-d` then break out of the `for /f` loop after the first line.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal

SET "pathsource=K:"

REM Get the newest pptx file in the specified directory. Get the filename and last modified timestamp
pushd "%pathsource%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir "*.pptx" /b /o:-d') DO (
    set "sourcefile=%%~nxa"
    set "timestamp=%%~ta"
    goto break
)
:break

ECHO %sourcefile%
echo %timestamp%

REM do other stuff with the %sourcefile% variable after this
```